# Como mover as bordas de posição após o hover?

Tags: html, css

Tenho essa `div` com bordas nos cantos e queria que a borda da direita fosse para baixo e a da esquerda para cima quando a div estiver em `hover` porém não consegui aplicar o efeito.

**Segue abaixo o que tentei:**

```css
div.classe {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgba(38, 166, 91, 0.5);
    margin-top: 30px;
    transition: all 0.4s  ease-in-out;
   
}
div.classe:after {
    content:"";
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-left: 4px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
    z-index:-1;
    margin-bottom:-4px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    border-color
}
div.classe:before {
    content:"";
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-right: 4px solid #000;
    border-top: 4px solid #000;
    z-index:-1;
    margin-top:-4px;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
div.classe:hover{
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}
div.classe:hover:before{
    content:"";
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-right: 4px solid #000;
    border-top: 4px solid #000;
    z-index:-1;
    margin-top:-4px;
    margin-right: -4px;
    border-color
}
div.classe:hover:after{
    content:"";
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-left: 4px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
    z-index:-1;
    margin-bottom:-4px;
    margin-left: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="classe">
texto qualquer
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode colocar o efeito após o `:hover` utilizando [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/::after) ou [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/::before).

Segue exemplo:

```css
div.classe {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgba(38, 166, 91, 0.5);
    margin-top: 30px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
   
}
div.classe:after {
    content:"";
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-left: 4px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
    z-index:-1;
    margin-bottom:-4px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    border-color
}

div.classe:before {
    content:"";
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-right: 4px solid #000;
    border-top: 4px solid #000;
    z-index:-1;
    margin-top:-4px;
    margin-right: -4px;
}

div.classe:hover{
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in;
}

div.classe:hover::after{
  border:none;
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 4px solid #000;
  border-top: 4px solid #000;
}

div.classe:hover::before{
  transform: translateY(30px);
  border:none;
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-right: 4px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="classe">
  <p>
  texto qualquer
  </p>
</div>
```

Seguindo a sugestão do [Gabriel.H](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/100381/gabriel-h) segue uma versão com "delay" na transição:

```css
div.classe {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgba(38, 166, 91, 0.5);
    margin-top: 30px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
   
}
div.classe:after {
    content:"";
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-left: 4px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
    z-index:-1;
    margin-bottom:-4px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    border-color
}

div.classe:before {
    content:"";
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-right: 4px solid #000;
    border-top: 4px solid #000;
    z-index:-1;
    margin-top:-4px;
    margin-right: -4px;
}

div.classe:hover{
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in;
}

div.classe:hover::after{
  border:none;
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 4px solid #000;
  border-top: 4px solid #000;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in;
}

div.classe:hover::before{
  transform: translateY(30px);
  border:none;
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-right: 4px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="classe">
  <p>
  texto qualquer
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Isso já resolveu muito meu problema, so uma pergunta tinha como fazer uma transição mais suave? tipo de deslisando pelas bordas?

Comment: Editei a pergunta veja agora.

Answer (score 2):

Amigo se quiser uma transição mais suave , adicione isto

```
-webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in;
-moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in;
-o-transition: 0.5s ease-in;
transition: 0.5s ease-in;
```

ao css da div.class, div.class:hover after and before

Comment: +1, estava pesquisando aqui kkk vou editar minha resposta adiconando uma versão com esse "delay"

Comment: kk , esta resolução funcionou pra você?

Comment: Adiconei na minha resposta, da uma olhada como ficou.

Comment: Tranquilo , não tinha certeza se ia funcionar por que eu mesmo nunca utilizei kkk